# Tsc does not compile the alias when building the app using nodemon

Tags: typescript, nodemon, tsc

I'm using this `tsconfig.json` configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "lib": ["ES2015"],
    "target": "ES2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "paths": {
      "@features/*": ["src/features/*"],
      "@api/*": ["src/api/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
    },
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

In `package.json`:

```
{
 "scripts": {
    "start:build": "tsc -w",
    "start:run": "nodemon dist/server.js",
    "start": "concurrently npm:start:*",
  },
 "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "7.6.0",
    "nodemon": "2.0.20",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  }
}
```

When I run the command `npm start` I got this issue:

```
[run] Error: Cannot find module '@features/user/user.routes'
[run] Require stack:
[run] - system/dist/api/routes.js
[run] - system/dist/api/app.js
[run] - system/dist/server.js
```

and it is related to this file `src/api/routes.ts`:

```
import Router from 'express'
import userRoutes from '@features/user/user.routes';

const router = Router()

router.use('/users', userRoutes)

export default router;
```

Should I add extra plugins for that as mentioned in [tsc - doesn't compile alias paths](https://github.com/LeDDGroup/typescript-transform-paths)? In the previous versions, there is no issue with alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by installing [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) and updating the `package.json`:

```
"_moduleAliases": {
    "@features": "dist/features",
    "@api": "dist/api",
    "@constants": "dist/constants"
  }
```